# Cordova how to watch files and rebuild when changed

Tags: cordova

I'm on cordova v10.0. I'm trying to figure out a `--watch` mode so that I don't have to quit and rebuild the app every time I change files.

I can't find anything in the docs. I found two plugins that appear to be no longer maintained:

- https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync#readme
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-livereload

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to live reload the build generated by Cordova but you can setup a development server in the browser for your JavaScript code (create-react-app, vue-cli...) if that helps.